# Sonata Bundle Error when configuring child admin

Tags: php, symfony, parent-child, sonata-admin

I'm using Symfony and the Sonata Bundle to generate my admin interface. I have 3 classes:

- Restaurant
- Service
- RestaurantService

With classes Restaurant and Service having a `OneToMany` relationship with RestaurantService.

I try `RestaurantService` as a child admin in Restaurant but I've got those errors:

> ContextErrorException in RestaurantAdmin.php line 143:
>
> Runtime Notice: Declaration of
> GSG\AdminBundle\Admin\RestaurantAdmin::configureSideMenu() should be
> compatible with
> Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin::configureSideMenu(Knp\Menu\ItemInterface
> $menu, $action, Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface $childAdmin =
> NULL)

and

> FileLoaderLoadException in classes.php line 13757:
>
> Runtime Notice: Declaration of
> GSG\AdminBundle\Admin\RestaurantAdmin::configureSideMenu() should be
> compatible with
> Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin::configureSideMenu(Knp\Menu\ItemInterface
> $menu, $action, Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface $childAdmin =
> NULL) in /Volumes/Data/ge0ra/www/admin_gsg/app/config/. (which is
> being imported from
> "/Volumes/Data/ge0ra/www/admin_gsg/app/config/routing.yml").

Here is my `services.yml` file:

```
services:
   sonata.admin.restaurant:
      class: GSG\AdminBundle\Admin\RestaurantAdmin
      tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Gestion des restaurants", label: "Restaurants" }
      arguments:
            - ~
            - GSG\AdminBundle\Entity\Restaurant
            - ~
      calls:
            - [ addChild, [@sonata.admin.restaurantservice]]
   sonata.admin.service:
      class: GSG\AdminBundle\Admin\ServiceAdmin
      tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Gestion des restaurants", label: "Services" }
      arguments:
            - ~
            - GSG\AdminBundle\Entity\Service
            - ~
   sonata.admin.restaurantservice:
      class: GSG\AdminBundle\Admin\RestaurantServiceAdmin
      tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Gestion des restaurants", label: "RestaurantServices" }
      arguments:
            - ~
            - GSG\AdminBundle\Entity\RestaurantService
            - ~
```

in my `RestaurantAdmin` class:

```
protected function configureSideMenu(MenuItemInterface $menu, $action, AdminInterface $childAdmin = null)
    {
        if (!$childAdmin && !in_array($action, array('edit'))) {
            return;
        }
 
        $admin = $this->isChild() ? $this->getParent() : $this;
 
        $id = $admin->getRequest()->get('id');
 
        $menu->addChild(
            'Voir/Editer',
            array('uri' => $admin->generateUrl('edit', array('id' => $id)))
        );
 
        $menu->addChild(
            'Services',
            array('uri' => $admin->generateUrl('sonata.admin.restaurantservice.list', array('id' => $id)))
        );
    }
```

and my `RestaurantServiceAdmin` class:

```
class RestaurantServiceAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected $parentAssociationMapping = 'Restaurant';

    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('service', 'sonata_type_model')
        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on filter forms
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        
    }

    // Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        if (!$this->isChild())
            $listMapper->addIdentifier('id')->addIdentifier('Restaurant');

        $listMapper
            ->add('service', 'sonata_type_model')
        ;
    }
}
```

Do someone have an idea from where those errors can come?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `RestaurantAdmin` class has the first parameter of `configureSideMenu` set as `MenuItemInterface $menu` when it should be an instance of `\Knp\Menu\ItemInterface`.

The `Menu` part of the type hint is wrong.

Comment: I forgot to say that I have this line on top of the page: `use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface as MenuItemInterface;`

Comment: Can you please update your code and add every use statement? The error tells you to use the same type hinting. Not only the ItemInterface could be missing but also the AdminInterface.